# How can I tell which "button" is being tapped in mobile Safari?

Tags: html, button, mobile-safari

I have an html "button" which is really just this:

```
<div onClick="window.location.href=somePage.htm">
    <img src="img.png"/>
</div>
```

Works fine in desktop Safari.  And it works in mobile Safari... however when I tap the "button" in mobile safari I don't see the little gray outline box indicating exactly what I'm tapping.  **How can I get this little gray outline box to show up?**  I find this feature of mobile Safari to be very useful and I'd like to provide it for the user.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that mobile Safari applies this to clickable elements only. Have a look at [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/handlingevents/handlingevents.html). I would suggest that you simply use a `<a>`-element for this purpose:

```
<a onclick="window.location.href = somePage.htm; return false;">
    <img src="img.png" />
</a>
```

This should work exactly like your `<div>` with a little styling.

Comment: ok using an anchor worked.  However I had to just do <a href="something.htm"... instead of using the onClick.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a link.